# How to check Ansible through gitlab CI?

Tags: ansible, gitlab

Our whole infrastructure is managed through ansible. We have a gitlab repo where all our ansible playbooks and roles are stored in. We recently added working gitlab-runner working, therefore we have to possibility to have a CI for each project. As our ansible repo is quite important, I was wondering if there is anything interesting to check ? I thought doing a `ansible-playbook --syntax-check`, but I'd like to know if there are more tests useful (maybe a linter ?).

I **don't want to** automatically run the playbooks, but only assert that the newly pushed roles/modifications are "good".

Thanksies,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you definitely want to run is [`yamllint`](https://yamllint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) which will make sure that all your yaml files are ok and respecting your coding standard. Make sure you configure the checks correctly in your `.yamllint` to be compatilble with `ansible-lint` below if you decide to use it (especially the line length). The following basic config should be a good start:

```
extends: default
rules:
  line-length:
    max: 160
    level: warning
```

You can then have your current syntax check

Finally, you probably want to run [`ansible-lint`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-lint). Although it will report most errors you will find above, this one will concentrate on good ansible practices, like not using shell when there is a module available, having names for all tasks, etc...

Side note: These are all default basic checks made by [`molecule`](https://molecule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) when you use it to test your roles. If you are developing independant reusable roles, I suggest you have a look at this tool.

If you don't want to run your playbooks, this is pretty much all I can see.

Comment: Just edited with an example  config file for yamllint. Glad I could help.

Comment: Haha, I finished adding yamllint to our pipeline and just found out your edit being the same thing as I did :p 

```
  line-length:
    level: warning
    max: 110
```